# Need help in simplifying $(\arcsin x)^3 + (\arccos x)^3$

Tags: trigonometry

If $a<\frac{1}{32}$, then what's the number of solutions of $$(\arcsin x)^3 + (\arccos x)^3 = a \pi^3\quad ?$$

I don't know what this condition restricts it to. Finally I get a quadratic equation in $\arcsin x$ . I can't proceed further.

Comment: If you have a quadratic equation $\alpha(\arcsin x)^2+\beta\arcsin x+\gamma=0$, you can just solve it in the variable $y=\arcsin x$ and then solve it of $x$.

Comment: I took it like this... For solution to exist ... The quadratic equation should have real roots. Correct?

Comment: It is indeed necessary. You must discard the ones that are $<-1$ or $>1$ as well.

Comment: @hanimohamed Sorry, my previous comment was meant to be "$<-\frac\pi2$ or $>\frac\pi2$", of course (the range of $\arcsin$ *is not* $[-1,1]$)

Comment: @HaniMohammed, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821252/sin-1-x-cos-1-x3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They teach you in algebra classes that:

$$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$

This can be easily seen considering an obvious root to $x^3+y^3=0$, $x^3=-y^3$, $x=-y$. $x=-y$ is a root, thus $x+y$ is a factor, and from here you can do long division.

Furthermore:

$$\arccos x + \arcsin x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

So,

$$(\arccos x)^3+(\arcsin x)^3=(\arccos x+\arcsin x)((\arccos x)^2-(\arccos x)(\arcsin x)+(\arcsin x)^2)$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}((\arccos x)^2-(\arccos x)(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos x)+(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos x)^2)$$

Comment: Yup... I applied it. I finally got 4x^2 -2pix +(1-8a).     Where, X is arcsin x

Comment: What where did the $a$ come from?

Comment: That's part of the whole question... Anyways I got it... Thanks!

Comment: I think what you got is wrong though.

Comment: U can further simplify by using arccos X = pi/2 - arcsin X or the other way round

Comment: Yes but how did you get $4$?

Comment: Use (a+b)^2 - ab inside the bracket. Then again sub pi/2

Comment: If we work with $X=\arcsin x$ then the equation I get is : $\frac{\pi}{2}X^2-\frac{(\pi)^2}{4}X+\frac{(\pi)^3}{8}=a(\pi)^3$.

Comment: Is....?????????

Comment: Sorry my mathstacks app was crashing.

Comment: Y do I see dollar symbols everywhere? Makes it difficult to read

Comment: Latex, click on the comment and click "render mathjax"

Comment: Take pi/2 common in lhs and take it to rhs

Comment: Then multiply both sides by 4

Comment: I checked it. Yup it's correct. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Wait let me take that back, I got: $4X^2-2\pi X+(\pi)^2(1-8a)=0$. Is that what you meant to say?