# redefining domain and range of inverse trigonometric ratios

Tags: trigonometry

If the domain and range of $\sin ^{-1}x$ are $\left[-1,1\right]$ and $\left[π/2,3π/2\right]$ and that of $\cos ^{-1}x$ are $\left[-1,1\right]$ and $\left[π,2π\right]$ respectively,then the minimum value of $${\left(\sin ^{-1}x\right)}^3+{\left(\cos ^{-1}x\right)}^3$$ is---

The above expression could be rearranged as $$π/2\left(\left({\sin ^{-1}x}\right)^2-\sin ^{-1}x\cos ^{-1}x+\left({\cos ^{-1}x}\right)^2\right)$$.I couldnot proceed after this.please help me in this regard.thanks.

Comment: @Qwerty But $\sin^{-1} -1= 3\pi/2$.

Comment: @Qwerty But why would the leftmost bound of the domain *have to* be mapped to the leftmost bound of the range...?

Comment: @Qwerty - standard convention on Intervals is that they have the lower value on the left, higher value on the right. There is no such requirement that their bounds be aligned with some function for which they happen to be domain or codomain.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821252/sin-1-x-cos-1-x3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the minimum does not occur at $x = \pm 1$. Let $f(x) = (\sin^{-1}x)^3 + (\cos^{-1}x)^3$. Then at the minimum, we should have $f'(x) = 0$. That is,
$$\frac {3(\sin^{-1} x)^2 - 3(\cos^{-1} x)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = 0$$
which simplifies to
$$(\sin^{-1} x)^2 = (\cos^{-1} x)^2$$
Since both functions are strictly positive, $$\sin^{-1} x = \cos^{-1} x$$
Letting $\theta = \sin^{-1} x$, this condition becomes $$\sin \theta = \cos \theta$$
On the intervals of definition, this occurs only at $\theta = \frac {5\pi}4$, where $x = -\frac{\sqrt 2}2$.

However, we need to test that original assumption that the minimum is not at either end. Now, $$f\left(-\frac{\sqrt 2}2\right) = 2\left(\frac{5\pi}4\right)^3 = \frac{125\pi^3}{32}$$ While $$f(1) = \left(\frac{\pi}2\right)^3 + (2\pi)^3 = \frac{65\pi^3}8 =  \frac{260\pi^3}{32}$$ and $$f(-1) = \left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)^3 + (\pi)^3 = \frac{35\pi^3}8 = \frac{140\pi^3}{32}$$

Thus the minimum really does occur at $x = -\frac{\sqrt 2}2$.